# unable to store read characters in a string (C++)

Tags: concatenation, fgetc

I am trying to read text in a file and store it in a string so that it can be output and read

although when I try to see the output string it seems to have a completely different output.
does anyone know why and what I can do to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str=' ';
    string myString = "";
    
    FILE* filepointer = fopen("C:/Users/user/Desktop/textfile.txt", "r");
    if (filepointer == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
    }
    else {

        while (!feof(filepointer)) {
            str=fgetc(filepointer);
            printf("%c",str);
           
            myString = myString + str;
         

        }
        fclose(filepointer);
        printf("\n\rmyString = %s ", myString);
    }
}
```

to be clear the content in the file is
t
te
tes
test
testi
testin
testing

this is the
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN7iX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to `printf` an `std::string`.

This doesn't work, because, since `printf` is a c function, it doesn't know about c++ strings.

You could use `std::cout << myString << std::endl` Or use the `c_str()` member function of myString to convert it to an c-style string.

```
printf("\n\rmyString = %s ", myString.c_str());
```

While the compiler accepts it just fine, it is usually things like this that makes people tell you not to mix c and c++.